# fatal: Not a Git Repository

Tags: git, ssh

So I have SSH working now no problemo and I have setup a new git repo in my

> /home/Tom/Git/myapp.git

I provided access to another drive for hosting the repo so the directory "Git" actually exists on D:\ using

> ln -s /cygdrive/d/Git/myapp.git

Now when I attempt to clone my git repo using

> ssh://name@ipaddress:port/Git/myapp.git

I get a

> fatal: '/Git/myapp.git' does not appear to be a git repository

Any ideas ?

**Edit:** I even created a directory just inside /Tom/myapp.git and tried to use

> git clone ssh://name@ipaddress:port/myapp.git

And i still get the error? Also try

> git clone -v ssh://name@ipaddress:port/~/myapp.git

Error is

> fatal: '~/myapp.git' does not appear to be a git repository 
>   Initialized empty Git repository in D:/Local/myapp/.git/ 
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

> `git clone ssh://name@ipaddress:port/~/Git/myapp.git`

(the important bit is `~` path component).

Comment: hey thanks for the response - tried that but still get the same error :( really no idea why this keeps popping up ?

Comment: Can you edit your post to add the *exact command* that gives you the grief? (of course feel free to change username and ip address)

Comment: But where is the `~` path component? And after you add it. Make sure you correctly reproduce error message.

Comment: My guess is then that cygwin doesn't really handle `~` and that would mean that you have to use ssh://name@ipaddress:port/home/Tom/myapp.git

Comment: hey thanks yeah also gave this a whirl but didnt help. i am really stumped - guess i keep looking

Comment: This is weird. It should work, but maybe there are problems with cygwin... Does it work if it's a real repository and not a symlink?

Comment: hey thanks again - any chance there is some path error. because it could be searching the wrong path or something - how do i check this ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. Do you mean `$PATH` environment variable? I think it's not the case, as the message comes from git (I believe).

Comment: hey thanks again - i am using msysgit, not sure whether this is a bug or not but really have no idea what to do now. i have tried using bash prompt and creating it from there but also get the same prob. is there anyway to check what path it thinks it is seeing?

Comment: ok i cloned successful from local "c:\SSH\home\Tom\myapp.git" - now just how to figure out what this is under ssh:// ?

Comment: HOORRRAAAYYY!!!! :D it had mapped the path not from /home/Tom/ - but rather from the root so when i mapped ssh://name@ipaddress:port/SSH/Home/Tom/myapp.git === happy days